# How do URLHelp and Keyword elements work in the definition of the Visual Studio code snippet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

When a snippet of code for C# in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is defined with either `URLHelp` or `Keyword` members, the url and the keyword does not show up anywhere on the screen:

- when the snippet is invoked
- when F1 is pressed after pressing Tab to autocomplete the snippet (there are no keywords / no URLHelp address in the web address)
- in Code Snippets Manager

So the question is, how those two members work or what am I doing wrong? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Author>xyz</Author>
      <Description>This is the description of the xyz snippet.</Description>
      <HelpUrl>www.microsoft.com</HelpUrl>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>dhcp</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
      <Shortcut>xyz</Shortcut>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>Cucumber title of the snippet.</Title>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[Hello world from xyz.]]>
      </Code> 
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- HelpUrl: According to Microsoft, it is never used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ms171429(v=vs.110).aspx This is also true for other versions of Visual Studio.
- Keywords: Microsoft claims that it is used "by online content providers" (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171433(v=vs.110).aspx) but I have not found a version of Visual Studio that actually does anything with the keywords.